# The modules store in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Im thinking of an html5/js mobile app, and I need to store the state of the application.
I'm figuring to use RequireJS, and RequireJs does hold the instances and scripts loaded into memory at runtime.

Does RequireJs have any hook where I can just ask RequireJs for all stored instances?
And also, can I somehow tell RequireJs here are all your stored instances?

Comment: Whether or not you can simply *store* the modules depends on the modules themselves. E.g. how do you store a DOM reference? You can't, so you will probably need to write your own store layer to only store the values that make sense to be stored, such as real user input, user data, etc. Having your code neatly split into models and views will go a long way to making your task more simple.

Comment: I haven't thougth a lot on that, but I guess I don't need it cause we are using KnockoutJS, and it would be easy to just re apply bindings. Actually I think DurandalJS will solve that out of the box :). I just need to setup RequireJs with the viewmodels instances for those requirejs modules